# django how to create a serializer ListField that accepts DictField with images values

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

As the title describes I need to create a Custom serializer ListField that accepts dictionary of string keys and value of Image

---

Example input:

```
[ {'1':FirstImage} , {'3',ThirdImage} ]
```

What I've tried:

```
customSerializer = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.DictField(
            child=serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, use_url=False)
        )
    )
```

---

Obviously my serializer doesnt work as it should, anyone have an idea how can I make this work?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Have you tried creating a separate serializer class having fields `serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, use_url=False)` and `IntegerField` then using that serializers as input to `ListField` serializer ?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is in failing to validate? (what does the error says)

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate serializer class and use that in your `ListField` like this:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    image = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, use_url=False)


class FinalSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     my_field = serializers.ListField(child=ImageSerializer())
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't add the child instance arg, as this will validate all the fields in the model table which will in turn increase endpoint latency.

As specified in the [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#composite-fields:%7E:text=longer%20actively%20maintained.-,Composite%20fields,-ListField):

> child - A field instance that should be used for validating the objects in the list. If this argument is not provided then objects in the list will not be validated.

You can write your own validator methods (just the relevant ones).